# getBitmap: FileNotFoundException: file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/IMG_20191029_101624.jpg (No such file or directory) (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

The app is crashing when I click on a gridview image and press the upload button to upload an image on firebase. The crash is happening because of converting the file to Bitmap before uploading. I have also given the permissions and allowed the app to access memory(read and write).

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Code:

```
fun getBitmap(imgUrl: String): Bitmap?
{
    Log.d("check location", "Parameter: $imgUrl")
    val imageFile = File(imgUrl)
    Log.d("check lcoation", "File: ${imageFile.toString()}")
    var fis: FileInputStream? = null
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null

    try
    {
        fis = FileInputStream(imageFile)
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis)
    }
    catch (e: FileNotFoundException)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "getBitmap: FileNotFoundException: ${e.message}")
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            fis!!.close()
        }
        catch (e: IOException)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "getBitmap: FileNotFoundException: ${e.message}")
        }

    }

    return bitmap
}
```

Log:

```
2019-10-30 /com.example.__ D/check location: Parameter: file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/IMG_20191029_101626.jpg
2019-10-30 /com.example.__ D/check lcoation: File: file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/IMG_20191029_101626.jpg
```

Error:

```
E/ImageManager: getBitmap: FileNotFoundException: file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/IMG_20191029_101626.jpg (No such file or directory)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.__, PID: 15275
    kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.example.__.utils.ImageManagerKt.getBitmap(ImageManager.kt:32)
        at com.example.__.data.FirebaseUserPhoto.uploadNewPhoto(FirebaseUserPhoto.kt:35)
        at com.example.__.viewModel.NextViewModel.uploadNewPhoto(NextViewModel.kt:48)
        at com.example.__.ui.share.NextFragment$onCreateView$2.onClick(NextFragment.kt:59)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: `and allowed the app to access memory` you mean you have implemented runtime permissions?

Comment: yes, and image are appearing from memory into gridview

Comment: @blackapps thanks, its working -> `getBitmap("storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/IMG_20191029_101626.jpg")`

Comment: `getBitmap("storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/IMG_20191029_101626.jpg")` No. If you remove `file://` you keep a leading slash: `getBitmap("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/IMG_20191029_101626.jpg")`

Comment: @blackapps it is working with both, slash and without slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `imgUrl` in `val imageFile = File(imgUrl)` starts with `file://`.

Remove it as `File()` does not expect a path starting with `file://`.